# How to dynamically disable a row's checkbox in react-bootstrap-table2?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I want to achieve something that is in my current sandbox:

[image]

Currently I've hardcoded the `nonSelectable: [1, 2]` so it will make row 1 and 2 unselectable.

Now I want to make the rows unselectable based on the file's createdByID.

If the file's `createdByID` is same with the user's login ID, then it will be selectable, else it won't, but **my issue now** is that how do I get each row's data and compare their `createdByID` with the user's ID then return the indexes that needs their checkbox to be disabled as an array to the `nonSelectable` prop?

I've found this [link](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/1297) but I'm not quite sure how to get it work as I am not sure where to get the `key`.

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-fast-99iln)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to generate the nonSelectable array programmatically for you. For example

```
function getNonSelectableRows(rows, userLoginId) {
  return rows
    .filter((r) => r.createdByID !== userLoginId)
    .reduce((acc, r) => {
      acc.push(r.fileID);
      return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

Then call the function for selectRow.nonSelectable

```
function App() {
  ...
  // I don't see the user login id in your code.
  // Thus I just add it as a constant at the top.
  const userLoginId = '200201';
  const [files] = useState([
    {
      fileID: 1,
      fileName: "Cardio Care Awareness Month",
      createdByID: "100101"
    },
    {
      fileID: 2,
      fileName: "MEMO COMPULSORY TO",
      createdByID: "100101"
    },
    {
      fileID: 3,
      fileName: "MEMO 2021 Covid19 Vaccination Leave",
      createdByID: "200201"
    },
    {
      fileID: 4,
      fileName: "Human Cell",
      createdByID: "200201"
    }
  ]);

  const selectRow = {
    mode: "checkbox",
    // nonSelectable = [1, 2]
    nonSelectable: getNonSelectableRows(files, userLoginId),
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <BootstrapTable
  keyField='id'
  columns={columns}
  rowStyle={rowStyle}
 data={data}
/>

 const rowStyle = (row) => {
        if (row.your_col_name=== 'your_condition') {
            return { backgroundColor: 'gray', color: '#999999', pointerEvents: 'none', cursor: 'not-allowed' };
        }
        return {};
    };
```

this works for me.